# My guest debian 7.7 boots on a terminal

Tags: console

I have VMware on my laptop and I installed a Debian 7.7 guest on it. An hour ago I powered off the debian, and when I booted it again, it came up with a terminal instead of my graphical environments. After login, I remain on the console.

Why isn't my graphical environment starting?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're logged in just type `startx` or `sudo service gdm restart`.

Comment: it says this error >>> please chek log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log " for additional information.                  server terminated with error (1) . closing log file .           xinit: giving up.        xinit: unable to connect to x server : connection refused.  plzzzzzzzzz what I do ?

Comment: Could you please post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` on your question using the code tags, or if this file is too long, post on pastebin.com and publish the url?

Comment: ok but it takes some minutes , sorry and thanks alot for your helping

Comment: ok I sended it in pasebin.com, plzzz go and see it, thanks

Comment: pastebin.com/index/fmjQ409H   <<<<< this is pastebin link